# How to speed up Linq based data fetching & Looping into different tables?

Tags: c#, sql, json, linq

I have a WPF application that uses a web-Service for fetch the list of Records. 
This list usually contains only 3 to 6 records having each records around 4 to 7 properties.

But to calculate these results I have to loop through LINQ statements.
For e.g.: see the code below (**note this code (methods used in) perform nested iterations to fetch values**):

```
public List<ReturnType> CalculateSomeResult(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, int tempID)
    {           
        //Start here...
        List<ReturnType> listResult = new List<ReturnType>();

        string aFormula = GetaFormula(tempID);  //  net worth
        int index = int.Parse(aFormula);

        SomeResult resultTotal = new SomeResult();
        resultTotal.NetWorth = getBeforeEndDate(index, tempID, 0, endDate);

        decimal[] incomes = CalculateProfit(startDate, endDate, tempID);
        decimal[] expenses = CalculateExpense(startDate, endDate, tempID);

        resultTotal.old = incomes[0] - expenses[0];
        resultTotal.current = incomes[1] - expenses[1];

        resultTotal.EndingNetWorth = resultTotal.NetWorth
            + resultTotal.old
            + resultTotal.current;


        ReturnType tempValTotal = new ReturnType();
        tempValTotal.objSomeResult = resultTotal;
        tempValTotal.Name = "Total";

        ReturnType tempVal = new ReturnType();

        using (DCMyDataContext context = new DCMyDataContext())
        {
            try
            {
                var currentEntity = context.Persons.Where(x => x.ID == tempID).FirstOrDefault();
                var contactList = getCByT(CT.I_O, tempID).OrderBy(x => x.ID).ToList();

                //This is where, it converts the DB String column value into 
                //JSON Object list
                List<jsonVal> jsonVals = jsonVal.fromJson<List<jsonVal>>(currentEntity.jsonVal);

                foreach (Contact contact in contactList)
                {                       
                    var objA = jsonVals.Where(x => x.ContactID == contact.ID &&
                        ((x.EndDate.HasValue == false) ||
                        (x.EndDate.HasValue == true && 
                        ((x.StartDate >= startDate && x.StartDate <= endDate) || 
                        (x.EndDate.Value >= startDate && x.EndDate.Value <= endDate)))));

                    var objPreviousA = jsonVals.Where
                        (x => x.ContactID == contact.ID &&
                        ((x.EndDate.HasValue == false) ||
                        ((x.EndDate.HasValue == true && (x.StartDate < startDate || x.EndDate.Value < startDate)))));

                    if (objA.Any() || objPreviousA.Any())
                    {
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    SomeResult result = new SomeResult();
                    result.NetWorth = getBeforeEndDate(index, tempID, contact.ID, endDate);


                    decimal oldIncome = 0;
                    decimal oldExp = 0;
                    decimal cIncome = 0;
                    decimal cExp = 0;
                    decimal lastaPercent = 0;
                    decimal lastIncomePercent = 0;

                    var lastjsonValRecord = objA.OrderByDescending(x => x.StartDate);
                    if (lastjsonValRecord.Any())
                    {
                        if (lastjsonValRecord.FirstOrDefault().a.HasValue)
                            lastaPercent = lastjsonValRecord.FirstOrDefault().a.Value;
                        if (lastjsonValRecord.FirstOrDefault().Income.HasValue)
                            lastIncomePercent = lastjsonValRecord.FirstOrDefault().Income.Value;
                    }
                    IEnumerable<int> incomeIDs = GetLeafAccountIDs(5, tempID);
                    IEnumerable<int> expenseIDs = GetLeafAccountIDs(6, tempID);

                    if (objA.Any())
                    {
                        foreach (jsonVal ownerRec in objA.ToList())
                        {
                            DateTime dtEnd = endDate;
                            if (ownerRec.EndDate.HasValue)
                                dtEnd = ownerRec.EndDate.Value;
                            if (dtEnd > endDate)
                                dtEnd = endDate;
                            DateTime dtStart = ownerRec.StartDate;
                            if (ownerRec.StartDate <= startDate)
                                dtStart = startDate;
                            decimal incomePercent = 0;
                            if (ownerRec.Income.HasValue) incomePercent = ownerRec.Income.Value;
                            if (incomePercent > 0 )
                            {
                                foreach (int id in incomeIDs)
                                {
                                    decimal bal = CalculateB(id, dtStart, dtEnd);
                                    cIncome += (bal * incomePercent / 100m);
                                }
                                foreach (int id in expenseIDs)
                                {
                                    decimal bal = CalculateB(id, dtStart, dtEnd);
                                    cExp += (bal * incomePercent / 100m);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (objPreviousA.Any())
                    {
                        foreach (jsonVal ownerRec in objPreviousA.ToList())
                        {
                            DateTime dtEnd = endDate;
                            DateTime dtStart = ownerRec.StartDate;
                            if (ownerRec.EndDate.HasValue)
                                dtEnd = ownerRec.EndDate.Value;
                            if (dtEnd > startDate)
                                dtEnd = startDate;
                            if (dtStart > startDate)
                                dtStart = startDate;

                            decimal incomePercent = 0;
                            if (ownerRec.Income.HasValue) incomePercent = ownerRec.Income.Value;
                            if (incomePercent > 0 && ownerRec.StartDate > new DateTime(1, 1, 1))
                            {
                                foreach (int id in incomeIDs)
                                {
                                    decimal bal = CalculateB(id, dtStart, dtEnd);
                                    oldIncome += (bal * incomePercent / 100m);
                                }
                                foreach (int id in expenseIDs)
                                {
                                    decimal bal = CalculateB(id, dtStart, dtEnd);
                                    oldExp += (bal * incomePercent / 100m);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    result.old = oldIncome - oldExp;
                    result.current = cIncome - cExp;

                    result.EndingNetWorth = result.NetWorth
                            + result.old
                            + result.current;

                    tempVal = new ReturnType();
                    tempVal.objSomeResult = result;
                    tempVal.Name = contact.FirstName;
                    listResult.Add(tempVal);
                }
            }
            catch 
            {
            }
        }

        listResult.Add(tempValTotal);

        //Reach here after 15 seconds...
        return listResult;

    }
```

When I debug this code It takes 1round 15 seconds to reach the return statement.

I tried to convert whole processing into SQL Stored proc, may be that will improve the processing speed. But I have a block point that in Database table I store the Json string in a column & the result of that is used here to obtain the results.

I know I need to create custom functionality to parse it to related table object in SQL. Or I need to change the default behaviour of saving Json string into column to save it into new Table instead.

But that’ll take a lot of time for me. 
I need any suggestions that I can take to speed-up the processing.
I’ll consider all & select that’ll fit for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reduce the number of queries you are making.  Since you know you are going to need to run `objA` and `objPreviousA` for each contact, instead of getting them one at a time, grab them all and put them into a list/dictionary in one call, then set objA/objPreviousA to the appropriate value in your loop.

Something like:

```
var contactIds=contactList.Select(c=>c.id).ToArray();
var objAs = jsonVals.Where(x => contactIds.Any(cid=>cid==x.ContactID) &&
                    ((x.EndDate.HasValue == false) ||
                    (x.EndDate.HasValue == true && 
                    ((x.StartDate >= startDate && x.StartDate <= endDate) || 
                    (x.EndDate.Value >= startDate 
                       && x.EndDate.Value <= endDate)))))
     .ToList();

foreach(var contact in contactList)
{
    var objA=objAs.Where(a=>a.ContactId==contact.id).ToList();
    ...
```

This should work for a small/medium sized amount of records.  If it gets too big, then you should convert to using a Dictionary instead of List, to reduce the lookup time in the loop.

Comment: I would also highly recommend you get a profiling tool to help you out to identify where your bottlenecks are, or at least use the built in stuff in EF 6. Add `context.Database.Log = l=> Debug.WriteLine(l);` after your `using` and watch the output window when you hit the webservice.

Comment: Well your idea to make minimum queries worked form me. I created almost single query with JOINs & Groupings nested within it & it now takes around 1.5 to 2 seconds. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should run a debug session and find the exact line that is taking most of the time.  It is almost impossible to check that code for you in a working environment (it could be a ton of things, sql takes too long to convert .ToList(), missing indexes, there are several calls there to some other methods, etc.)

If you run a debug session, you can log at each "section" of that code and then pay attention to the section that is taking most of the time and focus your attention to that particular line to find a solution to it.